# A question about the proof of Extension Lemma for Smooth functions

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

[image]

I am trying to understand the proof, but am stuck at the last line. Why does the first equality of the picture below holds? The codomain of $f$ is $R^k$, not some the set of nonnegative numbers. Is there something I am missing? I need hekp.

[image]

Comment: It might be a closure of a set.

Comment: What do you mean by "it"? Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: Why did you mention nonnegative numbers?

Comment: Because, nonzero elements in $R^k$ can add up to zero. So, there is no guarantee that the inclusion of the right side into left side on the first equality holds.

Comment: You should mention the reference.